# Why is the MPC's response so early?

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

I have a little question, I have designed an MPC to follow the reference trajectory, but I don't know why my MPC reacts so early. my Sampling time is 0.1s, the prediction step and the control step are Np=Nc=40,   in this case, the weighting factor for input is set to 0. Does anyone know  why the curve looks like this? How could I do, if I want the trajectory begins from the reference trajectory?[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using reference preview (i.e. you know the future changing reference) and here it is optimal to start moving before the reference changes (since the system reacts slowly), in order to achieve optimal performance in the long run. Roughly speaking you want to minimize the area between the yellow and red curve, and it is better to spread out that error on both sides, instead of lagging too much on one side (you probably have a quadratic measure, but the idea is the same)

Think of driving a car and approaching an uphill. You start accelerating before you enter the hill since you know the car will slow down soon.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but I think if the trajectory exact follow the reference trajectory, it would be under the reference trajectory or follow the shape of reference trajectory, isn|t it?

Comment: That is under the assumption that you can follow the reference. In your case, you cannot (the system is too slow, i.e. the reference is changing too quickly). Once again a car analogy: Your cannot accelerate faster than what the engine is capable of, so a changing velocity reference from 0km/h to 100km/h in 3 seconds is just impossible to track perfectly.

Comment: And also note that this probably is very dependent on the type of penalty. With a quadratic cost, it is very expensive with large error, but pretty cheap with small, while if you use linear costs small and large errors are penalized relatively the same. THat means a quadratic cost will prefer small negative and some small positive errors (current) rather than relatively larger errors with same sign on all (i.e. shifting the yellow curve to the right which would lead to very large errors during a couple of seconds)